# how to set an mvc object to a variable within webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application with a link to print the information. the print link is inside a javascript. 
code as follows:
    
    <%= Html.TextBox("Name", Model.ApplicantStatus.Name) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*") %>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myEmail = "ChangeMe@abc.org";
var mySubject = "Sample";
var myBody = "My name is ";
var myName = Model.TableName.Name;
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + myEmail + '?subject=' + mySubject + '&body=' + myBody + myname + '">email me</a>');
 </script>
```

---

basically var myName = Model.TableName.Name; is not working. any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in the string output tag and enclose it in quotes.

```
var myName = '<%= Model.TableName.Name %>';
```

You need to use the string output tag to get the actual content from the variable.  It needs to be in quotes to treat it as a string, otherwise it attempts to find a javascript object with that name.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that little detail.

Comment: Although I just tried it w/out the quotes and it still works on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <%= Model.TableName.name %>